# Issue using assemblies and namespaces in msxsl

Tags: c#, linq, xslt, msxsl

I have an XSL transform that is using msxsl to add extension methods in C#.  I have the following setup for msxsl:

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="cs">
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Linq" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Xml.Linq" />
```

I then have a c# function as an extension method:

```
public int returnUniqueCount(string theCodeCollection) {
      // calculate and return the total number of distinct codes
      if (theCodeCollection.Length > 0) {
        string[] myObject = theCodeCollection.Split('|');
        string[] uniqueCollection = myObject.Distinct().ToArray();
        return uniqueCollection.Length;

      } else {
        return 0;

      }

    }
```

Essentially that just takes a tokenized string, splits it, and counts the result set excluding duplicates.

The transform runs fine on the server, but when I try to profile it, I get the following error:

```
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct'
```

I've been bashing my head against this all morning and I'm just not seeing it.  Any ideas?

Thanks all.

Comment: What do you mean by: "when I try to profile it ..."? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Are you running/compiling with a different version of .NET when you profile?

Comment: Same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49493100/3083333

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, apparently template methods that has a template return are not available for scripting, only methods that has a distinct return like ContainsKey() and Count are availble.