# Inline c# in XSLT results in weird behavior

Tags: c#, linq, xslt, msxsl

I generated an xsl stylesheet with some inline c# code. I need to use it in an asmx application running on IIS. This is an excerpt of the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl in lang user" xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0" xmlns:lang="http://www.composite.net/ns/localization/1.0" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
  <msxsl:assembly name="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  <msxsl:assembly name="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />


    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Linq"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
    <![CDATA[

    private static string GenerateLine(string what, int howmuch)
    {
      var unuseful_var = "";
      return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(what, howmuch).ToArray()).Substring(0, howmuch);
    }

    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lines">
    <xsl:for-each select="line">
      <xsl:value-of select="user:GenerateLine("-", 10)" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the application, I use the xsl in this way:

```
XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
...
transformer.Load(xsltReader, new XsltSettings() { EnableScript = true }, null);
transformer.Transform(xmlReader, null, outputStream);
...
```

Everything works fine, in the test application **but** when I deployed the same exact code and xsl stylesheet in the web application, suddenly, the xsl transformation raises exceptions like:

- The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found ( are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
- 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray'

Googling I found this (maybe) [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8300790/3083333) but it is still without answers.

I solved the issues with some workarounds but I definitely would like to know what is going on under the wood.

Thank you

Comment: When was `var` added to C#? Sounds as if the compiler used in your web application doesn't know it so I suppose it tries to compile your embedded C# with a rather old version of the C# compiler that does not recognize `var`.

Comment: I thought the same exactly thing but the code that is doing the transformation is the same as the one running via the webapp in IIS becase I exported it as a standalone DLL. Plus, everything (DLL, IIS web app and xsl) is targeting the .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: IIS application pool might run under lower .NET version probably?

Comment: @Evk you were right!! The IIS application pool was targeting .NET CLR version 2.0, switching it to v4.0 solved the exceptions. Thank you to point me to the right direction